# How can I solve memory allocation error in R?

Tags: r, out-of-memory

I am using a package named `timereg` in R. But, when I am fitting a model this shows some kind of problem. (My sample size is n=4500)

```
library(timereg)    
fit <- Gprop.odds(Surv(time,status==1)~prop(age)+prop(sex)+prop(fedu)+ prop(wi) ,dat,max.time=7,n.sim=400)
    Error in Gprop.odds(Surv(time, B5 == 1) ~ prop(mageB) + prop(B4) + prop(fedu) +  : 
      'Calloc' could not allocate memory (13583 of 8 bytes)
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the value of `memory.limit()` ? How does that compare to you system RAM? You can expand memory via `memory.size( size )` , size specified in MB if you want more RAM available to R.

Comment: Values are memory.size() = 48.05 and memory.limit() 3000. My RAM is 2 GB. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: well your memory.limit() > RAM so that's not the issue. Try using a random sample of your data. Otherwise we don't know enough to help. We don't know what else is using your RAM.

Comment: The amount of memory requested that caused the error is tiny. Some other process, possibly not related to R is consuming free space. Restart your computer with minimal number of applications running concurrently and try again with as few objects in your workspace as possible.